# MATLAB: Reading space separated float values from tex file

Tags: matlab, file, textscan

I am reading a text file using the [textscan](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/textscan.html) [function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html#btg0kfn) of MATLAB. **Problem here is that nothing is being read in `value`** as the floating points are separated with three spaces and I am quite new in MATLAB programming to use some efficient syntax. My current code is given below:

**Code:**

```
values = textscan(input_file, '%f   %f   %f   %f   %f\n %*[^\n]');
```

The input file follows the following format:

**File:**

```
0.781844   952.962130   2251.430836   3412.734125   4456.016362
0.788094   983.834855   2228.432996   3196.415590   4378.885466
0.794344   967.653718   2200.798973   3119.844502   4374.097695
```

If the floating point values are `#` separated then the below statement works fine:

```
values = textscan(input_file, '%f#%f#%f#%f#%f\n %*[^\n]');
```

Is there any solution except for tokenization ?

Comment: Could you give a sample string from a file that you are trying to read (i.e. example how does your input look like)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a delimiter, also you should activate the MultipleDelimsAsOne in order to treat the repeated space as a single delimiter:

```
value = textscan(input_file, '%f   %f   %f   %f   %f \n ','Delimiter',' ','MultipleDelimsAsOne',1);
```

If needed you can also specify several delimiters at the same time:

```
del = {';',' '};
```

Comment: this doesn't work. are you sure there are spaces in the format specifier string ?

Comment: Looking at the example in the documentation, it seems like you can just use a single space for the delimiter. Have you tried that?

Comment: I edited my answer, I test this code on your sample and everything work.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to use textscan, you could probably use importdata. There you can specify the delimiter as a parameter. 
Documentation http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html

Code example

```
filename = 'myfile01.txt';
delimiterIn = '   ';
A = importdata(filename,delimiterIn);
```

Comment: I am reading the file, line by line. I may have to change the whole logic to use import data.